# Is there a way to programmatically retrieve total VRAM, free VRAM and GPU usage?

Tags: video, memory

I am looking at profiling my app, although there is no facility that I was able to find, that is giving me VRAM data for my ATI GPU, like total VRAM on board, used and free VRAM amount and GPU load in percentage.

I can use third party software maybe; but I wonder if it is possible to use terminal or something like python to get this info. On Windows the issue does not seem to be present; but on OSX for some reason, getting such data seems to be quite involved, especially for ATI cards.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Surely any app will just use the resources that the OS can make available? What do you mean by "profiling my app"? Is this an app that you've written that you're trying to optimize in some way?

Comment: Yes,I wrote an app that is performing different 3d operations and I am trying to optimize it. I can get some data from the system profiler but it is not really precise. I want to trigger operations in my applications and see where it spikes as far as memory consumption and GPU usage, so I can optimize